# replace string by index of this string

Tags: c#, string

Hello so i have a text file that looks like

```
45353
b
4353
b
54
54
b
5345
53453
```

and array list that looks like

```
A
B
A
```

how can i replace string b->A b - > b - > A ?

OUTPUT SHOUDL LOOK like

```
45353
A
4353
B
54
54
A
5345
53453
```

Comment: What? Can you at least provide what your expected output will be?

Comment: I have no idea what you talking about.

Comment: Edit still makes no sense. What's the condition for replacing `b` with `A` instead of `B`? Have you even tried anything? Or are you just trying to get SO to do it for you?

Comment: output added to question

Comment: condition is the encounter of string in file.

Comment: OK, definitely voting to close: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Regex.Replace(String, String, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx) for this, execute until all of the intended replacements from `arr` are replaced.

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
var arr = new[] { "A", "B", "A" };
var regex = new Regex("b");
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
    text = regex.Replace(text, arr[i].ToString(), 1);
```

Tip: Never answer when tired...

Answer (score 3):

```
string content = File.ReadAllText("data.txt");
var replacements = new[] { "A", "B", "A" };

int index = 0;
string result = Regex.Replace(content, @"[a-zA-Z]+",
                              m => replacements.Length > index ? 
                                   replacements[index++] : m.Value);
```

This will execute `MatchEvaluator` for each found word, and replace it with value from appropriate position in `replacements` array.

Answer (score 0):

Read the 2nd file into an array of strings

Keep a counter initialized to 0

Read from the 1st file, every-time your data matches the replacement condition, replace it with the value at the counter and increment the counter

Comment: (not posting code since I dont have VS set up right now and my C# syntax is a bit rusty)

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt");
int counter = 0;
List<string> arrayFromFile = new List<string>();
while(string line = sr.ReadLine())
{
   if(line=='b')
   {
      line = abaArray[counter];
      counter++;
      if(counter>=abaArray.Length)
      {
         counter=0;
      }
   }
   arrayFromFile.Add(line)
}
//Write back to the file
```